# How to bring set of elements to immediate next line using css

Tags: css, newline

**What I am trying to do ?**

I am trying to bring set of elements starting from the last element to immediate next line using CSS.

[example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahtishamchishti/eyasn8rj/17/)

**html:**

```
<div id="test">
  <button class="t_btn"> btn1 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn2 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn3 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn4 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn5 </button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#test .t_btn:nth-last-child(-n+3){
    display: block;
}
```

**This is what I want:**

[image: target]

Comment: Will there always be 5 elements?

Comment: well the count of buttons would be known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea with flexbox. The trick is to add a hidden element that will push your elements by changing the orders:

```css
#test {
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
}
#test:before {
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  order:1;
}

#test .t_btn:nth-child(n+4){
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <button class="t_btn"> btn1 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn2 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn3 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn4 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn5 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn6 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn7 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn8 </button>
</div>
```

Or like this:

```css
#test {
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
}
#test:before {
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  order:1;
}

#test .t_btn:nth-last-child(-n+3){
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <button class="t_btn"> btn1 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn2 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn3 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn4 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn5 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn6 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn7 </button>
  <button class="t_btn"> btn8 </button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried it too `#test .t_btn:nth-last-child(-n+3){order:2;}`

Comment: @Paulie_D well, I didn't unrestand it this way ;) I though the first line is fixed number not the last .. will edit with both solution

Comment: You might need to check for browser compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @Jishad it's supported everywhere ;) its support is the same as the flexbox support .. so only very old IE will fail as they always do